# Intellij IDEA: element forkCount is not allowed here

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a java project using maven-surefire-plugin like this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m</argLine>
        <forkCount>1C</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
        <disableXmlReport>false</disableXmlReport>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The project is working and is tested fine but Intellij is reporting *element forkCount is not allowed here* for both *forkCount* and *reuseForks*. Why this happens and how I can solve it?

Comment: Try specifying the plugin's version explicitly and check with the last version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download File the https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA if you see the same error.

Comment: sorry, the’re is a pluginManagement section specifying the last numerical version for it

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the 'plugins' element in a 'pluginManagement' element.
This fixed it for me, along with other issues.